# Get all files in a foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have some `<input type="file">` that are generated dynamically by `jQuery`.
That means that the `name attribute` of each `input` is also generated dynamically, is a number and increments by 1 every time a new `input` appears in the DOM.

I need something like a `foreach loop` to get all the inputs in my `php`.
I have tried to upload 1 file and i have left 3 `inputs` empty because my inputs are in a row and i wanted to upload only one image and not 4. i looped through this `$all = Input::file();` and the `var_dump` response is this

`NULL object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "index.jpeg" ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(9408) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpSVn3Tb" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phpSVn3Tb" } NULL NUL`L

I know that my question is a little bit difficult to understand, but i can not find a better way to explain the problem.

**Edit:**
These are my default inputs:

```
<div class="row">
<input type="file" name="1">
<input type="file" name="2">
<input type="file" name="3">
<input type="file" name="4">
</div
```

When the user presses a button, jQuery appends

```
<div class="row">
<input type="file" name="5">
<input type="file" name="6">
<input type="file" name="7">
<input type="file" name="8">
</div>
```

and every time the button is pressed, as well

```
<div class="row">
<input type="file" name="9">
<input type="file" name="10">
<input type="file" name="11">
<input type="file" name="12">
</div
```

Then in `php` i need to get all the inputs that have a value.

What i have done is:

```
$all = Input::all()
foreach ($all as $one => $two) 
   var_dump($two);
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Please use <input type="file" name="files[]">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Form for multiple File uploads:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'url_to_controller','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
```

And all your files should have a specfic name for the upload, like this:

```
{!! Form::file('files[]', array('multiple'=>true)) !!}
```

Then you can use your Controller:

```
class UploadController extends Controller {
   public function store() {

   $files = Input::file('files');
```

And loop through all files

```
 foreach($files as $file) {
   ....
```

Comment: Looks nice, but the `names` of the inputs are numbers that are generated dynamically. What i can do for this?

Comment: Why that? All "files" should have an array as "name" -> like files[] if you need multiple file uploads, and not "file1","file2","file3"

Comment: Otherwise you could use in a loop -> if (Input::hasFile('file."$i'")) { .... - but i totally recommend to use an array here