# PHP foreach($images as $image) not uploading images

Tags: php, lumen

I am trying to upload multiple images to my server, however it is not working. It gives me status code 200 but it doesn't upload images.

This is what I do:

```
if($request->hasFile('post_image')){
   $images = $request->post_image;
   $i = 0;
   foreach($images as $image){
           $i++;
           $filename = $post->id.'.'.$i.'jpg';
           $location = '/var/www/site/html/'.$post->id;
           $image->move($location, $filename);
    } 
 }
```

If I am removing the `foreach()` then it uploads image but only one.

Why it is not uploading them? What I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Answering my own question here also. The problem was that my key "`post_image`" had to be "`post_image[]`" instead.

Comment: did `$image->move()` work outside of foreach?

Comment: @chandlerbing yes, outside foreach, it uploads image.

Comment: Do you really want to upload files like `post_id.0jpg`? Because you are appending `'.'` before `$i`.

Comment: Is the images field setup as an array? `<input name="images[]" type="file" />`

Comment: Does `'/var/www/site/html/'.$post->id;` exist? Pretty sure the destination folder would need to exist first.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone just tried. It doesn't change the thing.

Comment: @Classified I am using Lumen, so I do it restfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my key "`post_image`" had to be "`post_image[]`" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `.` before 'jpg' extension in your filename:
Should be like this:

`$filename = $post->id.'.'.$i.'.jpg';`

Comment: You are right but it doesn't change the fact that it doesn't upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this way upload multiple images:

```
   if(!empty(Input::file('image'))){
    $files= Input::file('image');
    $destinationPath= 'images';
    $images=array(); 
   foreach($files as $file){
    $fullname= $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
    $hashname  = $fullname; 
    $upload_success   =$file->move($destinationPath, $hashname);
    $images[]=$fullname;
    $has= implode(",",$images);
      }

    $categories = new CategoryType;
    $categories->name = Input::get('name');
    $categories->image_attachment    =  $has;  
    $categories->save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this awnser you can loop on the all uploaded files

[Get all files in a foreach loop in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909131/get-all-files-in-a-foreach-loop-in-laravel)

like `$images = Input::file('post_image');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_ary = array();
        $file_count  = count($request->file('image') );
        $a=($request->file('image'));
        $finalArray=array();

        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
                $fileName = time().$a[$i]->getClientOriginalName();
                $destinationPath = $request->input('path') ;
               $finalArray[$i]['image']=$destinationPath.$fileName;
                  $a[$i]->move($destinationPath,$fileName);

        }
       return json_encode($finalArray);
```